# Command Line Authentication in Web2py

Tags: authentication, command-line-interface, web2py, pam

I have made a web interface for my project using web2py and configured login with pam. Now i have to make a CLI for the same. I could not find any way i can authenticate the user (we can assume that the user i want to authenticate is already logged in on the linux machine configured with pam and running web2py).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to find out the name of the logged in user:

```
username = os.getlogin()
```

Then you force a login:

```
from gluon.storage import Storage
from uuid import uuid4
session.auth = Storage(user=user, last_visit=request.now,
                                   expiration=auth.settings.expiration,
                                   hmac_key = str(uuid4())
```

we are about to add a auth method to do this in one line.

Comment: How do we use this session for making xmlrpc calls ?

Comment: +1 for the example... has the one-liner been added to web2py yet?  If so, can you post a link to the docs, or otherwise show how to use the native API?

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Massimo said, this one-line login has been implemented now. You can do so using the following code:

```
#User_id is whatever the id is for the user you are forcing them to log in to
auth.login_user(user_id)
```

I couldn't find any documentation on this in the book but you can take a look at the method yourself in the gluon.tools module in the source.